# Is it possible to implement Socrata Data lens in .net mvc

Tags: socrata

Recently i came to know about the socrata data lens feature.Is it possible to use this  feature in my .net project?. if so is there a way to implement it in my code.I searched in many place but what i found was, how its working in the socrata. Please help me in this as am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socrata Data Lens is a feature of our platform, and is not offered as an open source tool.

If you're looking for something you could use from within a .NET web application, you might want to check out [VizWit](https://github.com/timwis/vizwit) which allows you to make DataLens-like visualizations that run within a web browser.

Comment: What i ment by this post is that, suppose  am using the socrata data set and through soql am fetching the data in to my project.But while fetching the data its taking too much time.so i got the information that by using data lens feature i can make the fetching faster.but i dont know how to use it in to my project.Is there a way.I completely agree that it your own platform feature,but the same like the SoQl is there any possibility of using it.May be my understanding is wrong.if so please correct me. @chrismetcaif

Comment: DataLens is also implemented using SODA and SoQL, but we should make sure you're using the latest, fastest API endpoints and efficient SoQL queries. Can you share the datasets you're using and some of your queries?